# Jekyll plugin doesn't print variable out

Tags: ruby

Right so I'm trying to do something dead simple, which is go through some files and print out the contents. This is my `_plugins/test.rb` file:

```
module Jekyll
  class TestPlugin < Liquid::Tag
    def render(context)
      Dir.glob("somefolder/*.someextension") do |my_file|
          file = File.open(my_file)
          contents = file.read
          # print contents
      end
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('testplugin', Jekyll::TestPlugin)
```

Now considering the env, a simple `puts contents` will output correct contents to the console. However, I want this to just spit out contents when called via `{% testplugin %}`. I've tried the following combinations:

```
"contents"
#{contents}
#{@contents}
print contents
print "contents"
print #{contents}
print #{@contents}
```

None of which output anything when called via `{% testplugin %}`. When I swap out my `Dir.glob` stuff for something like `"Hello there"`, the output will be correct. Needless to say I'm very unfamiliar with Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that `Dir.glob` when given a block (as you've done) will [call the block once for each matching filename but then returns `nil`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob).

This means that your `render` method isn't actually returning anything.

One solution is to call `glob` without a block. It will then return a list of the matching filenames and you can map this to the contents of the files.

For example to return the combined contents of all the matching files:

```
def render(context)
  Dir.glob("somefolder/*.someextension").map do |filename|
    File.read(filename)
  end.join("\n")
end
```

Comment: That makes sense and works! In this specific instance, I'd like to perform some operations with the file name as well as contents, and output that in the context of file contents itself, so I wouldn't necessarily join them, but I understand the idea!

Comment: By the way, would there be a reason this outputs everything in reversed order? I have `file1` and `file2`, it'll output `file2` first

Comment: The order would just depend on the order of the filenames returned by `glob`, so you might need to add a sorting step: `Dir.glob("somefolder/*.someextension").sort.map ...`